# LDAP multiple locations

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there a way to add multiple locations here?  I need to do this for testing purposes and to add ldap filter on multiple locations. Currently, I only have one location. I would like to test with at least two locations.

```
<Employees FileFormat="LDAP"
             FilePath="LDAP://LDAPS.company:6367"
             Filter="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(givenName=*)(sn=*)(mail=*)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=Test Location))"
             FilterOptions="Subtree">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "location"? Are you referring to the `FilePath`, or `physicalDeliveryOfficeName`?

Comment: physicalDeliveryOfficeName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LDAP "or" operator, which is `|`, like this:

```
Filter="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(givenName=*)(sn=*)(mail=*)(|(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=Test Location)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=Test Location 2)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=Test Location 3)))"
```

More details about how to build LDAP queries is here: [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)